# Parse native byte array out of OLE object in Ms-Access

Tags: c#, ms-access

For an updater application, we are storing firmware files into an MS-Access database. The firmware-files are stored in MS-Access typical OLE-objects.

I want to read out of the OLE-object a byte array with the original content of the file. I have now already access to the data and meta-data of the OLE-object. Are there any native parsers available to strip the meta-data off? I am just interested in the original content.

The updater application is written in C#. I need the byte array in the application. The link with the database is already working fine.

Comment: Why not storing the raw firmware data in a blob?

Comment: You can use Blob fields with the "memo" type or "ole-object" type. For some reason, the memo field does not allow multiple kilobytes data. I use the frontend of Access to fill the database. The communication with the user is easy there. Maybe are there other ways of storing a blob in MS Access?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to avoid using access front end to fill the database and use the following VBA code instead to store binary data: support.microsoft.com/kb/103257
You can then use www.codeproject.com/Articles/16851/Uploading-and-Downloading-BLOBs-to-Microsoft-Acces to read/write data to access using c#